# URL querystring based login behavior asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config, autologin, querystringparameter

I have the following issue,

In web.config we have authentication which says any access to files under secure folder will be redirected to login page

Now the change i need to make is if the request is from a particular domain then allow access without login, that is,

if the url is http://www.abc.com/secure/home.aspx     ---> redirect to login and users shud login

if the url is http://www.abc.com/secure/home.aspx?uid=steve&fname=john    ---> they should be able to access home.aspx and should not be redirected to login page

I need to configure web.config file in such a way that if there are any parameters that are sent along with the url then do not redirect

how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to disable the redirect in your formsauthentication specification in your web.config.  Then, you will need to do your own redirect in a similar way to how the authentication module does it.  You will need to add to the application pipeline your check.  That is, in the global.asax.cs file, application_authenticaterequest method?